# error inserting/Updating row in pentaho?

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am trying to insert data from CSV file to Table Output in pentaho .

I got following error

```
 2015/04/28 01:07:14 - Table output.0 - Connected to database [vps] (commit=5000)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : Because of an error, this step can't continue: 
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - Error inserting row into table [fk_test] with values: [NFT-140721054GN00079XXXXXXX], [postpaid], [NON-FA], [L23-APRICOT/PINK-115(40)], [null], [OD40709024274], [82662472], [9-Jul-14], [10-Jul-14], [null], [null], [21-Jul-14], [return_completed], [1], [1379], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [39.5], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0.3], [0], [0], [NATIONAL], [0], [0], [0], [0], [FKST-00151], [10-Jul-14], [1379], [sandal], [0], [0], [0]
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - 
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - Error inserting/updating row
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - ERROR: value too long for type character varying(21)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - 
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - 
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:377)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.processRow(TableOutput.java:118)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - Error inserting/updating row
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - ERROR: value too long for type character varying(21)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - 
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.insertRow(Database.java:1268)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:255)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  ... 3 more
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(21)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)


2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:365)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.insertRow(Database.java:1235)
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 -  ... 4 more
2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=186, R=187, W=186, U=0, E=1)
```

2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - Error inserting/updating row

2015/04/28 01:08:05 - Table output.0 - ERROR: value too long for type character varying(21)

how i can solve this error .

I checked table defination in postgresql  there data type is character varying without size

Comment: What is the data type set to on the 'Fields' tab of the `Text file input` step? If it has a number (like 21), try just removing it.

Comment: The PostgreSQL log should have more information about the value and column.

Comment: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(21) <-- you have a varchar(x) field in the target table and you're trying to insert a string that doesn't fit. The data row is in the log, it should be easy to check whether all fields match the expected lengths.

Answer (score 1):

The error is

```
ERROR: value too long for type character varying(21)
```

and there are two values that are over 21 characters.

```
NFT-140721054GN00079XXXXXXX
L23-APRICOT/PINK-115(40)
```

You need to either shorten the values or change the character size for the columns in the table `fk_test`